# Using Len with Left (or Mid) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that looks like this:
[image]

And what I need to do is to remove every individual "NA" from the range, using VBA. Without shifting cells.

I can't do (replace), because it's possible that there could be "na" in the other strings.
I assume "Instr" won't work for the same reason.

I tried a couple methods, which I thought would work, but for the reasons I can't understand, they don't.

At first I tried Left + Len, like this:

```
dim nb as workbook

for i = 2 to nb.sheets(1).cells(rows.count, 17).end(xlup).row

if left(range("Q" & i).value, 2, "NA", Len(range("Q" & i).value)) then
nb.sheets(1).range("Q" & i).value = ""

end if
next i
```

When that did not work, I tried this:

```
for i = 2 to nb.sheets(1).cells(rows.count, 17).end(xlup).row

if mid(range("Q" & i).value, 0 + 2, Len(range("Q" & i).value)) And _
Instr(1, (range"Q" & i).value), "NA") then
nb.sheets(1).range("Q" & i).value = ""

end if
next i
```

I also tried many other ways to rearrange Len, Left and Mid, but none worked.

And even though the solution doesn't have to be done using Left (mid) and Len, is there a way to do it this way? And if not, what other ways there are?

Comment: Why can't you do replace and just specify a whole cell match?

Comment: You are completely right! I forgot about whole cell match. Thank you for reminding! However, is there still a way to do this using Left and Len?

Comment: Yes: `if left(range("Q" & i).value, 2) = "NA" then` but it's **very** inefficient, and actually introduces the problem of cells that **begin** with "NA" being affected.

Comment: @Rory `if left(range("Q" & i).value, 2) = "NA" and Len(range("Q" & i).value) >2 then` but your still does not make it more efficient

Comment: I had exactly the same train of thought initially. That is why i also included Len with left to make sure that the code would replace only those "Lefts = "NA"" which length is 2, but failed...

Comment: Why wouldn't you just test if the cell value is "NA" though? Why complicate it even further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Replace if you specify `Lookat:=xlWhole`

```vb
With nb.Sheets(1)
    .Range("Q2:U" & .Cells(.Rows.Count,"Q").End(xlUp).Row) _
    .Replace "NA", "", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your solution achieves exactly what i need. Do you still maybe know a way to achieve this using Left and Len?

Answer (score 0):

This updates each cell in the `Range` you specify.

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:Z100")
        If c.Value = "NA" Then c.Value = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

But for something this simple, it makes more sense to just use the built-in Replace.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if the range is dynamic though?

Comment: You can build the `Range` any way you like, it won't matter. It simply runs once for each cell in the Range you specify.